# Applying for fellowships in the UK with different UK host scientists

Tags: application, funding, postdocs, united-kingdom

I have finished my PhD recently, and now I am applying for postdoctoral positions. I am not a UK or EU citizen. Assume that I would like to apply for two different fellowships in the UK (for example, among those described [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/vacancy/#Royal_Society)), with different UK based host scientists. Let's say I would like to apply for a scheme A together with X and for a scheme B together with Y, where A is not equal to B and X is not equal to Y.

Could such "double application" hinder my chances?

Comment: It might be close to double the work involved, as some proposal formats can be rather different!

Comment: Are the fellowships from completely different funding agencies/ councils? You should check because in the UK there are several different funding councils, but some are related and have multiple fellowships or share fellowships (e.g. Royal Society & Britac) and others prohibit you from applying to more than one fellowship from certain councils (ESRC). Look up "research councils UK." Also may depend on what referee system they use - you may run the risk of your proposal being sent out to the same evaluators.